# How can I optimize this Java graphics2d rendering process for 256 color PNG images?

Tags: java, game-engine, graphics2d

I'm working on a prebuilt tile-based game engine for a Software Engineering class and initially used 16 color PNG files to load in the tilesets. On my Lenovo y510p with a 2.4ghz i7 Haswell processor and a nVidia GTX 750m, I got around 62 FPS which is extremely low for how little was being rendered. After upgrading the tileset to a 256 color image, the framerate is sitting at around 27 which is completely unpresentable. Is there any way I can optimize the rendering process to make the game run at a more acceptable framerate?

Code is too large to fit so I've hosted it on pastebin.

[Game.java](http://pastebin.com/d6qLsLdQ)

[Sprite.java](http://pastebin.com/U5bbA0yR)

Comment: Have a look at [`BufferStrategy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html) and [BufferStrategy and BufferCapabilities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/bufferstrategy.html).  It's a very bad idea to try and render directly to a top level container like `JFrame`, I would have started with a `JPanel` and used it's `paintComponent`, it's double buffered by default for starters.

Comment: And if you have a performance problem then *profile your program's performance*.  You need to know where the program is spending its time to effectively reduce the amount of time consumed.

Comment: The likely issue is you seem to be redrawing all the sprites on each cycle, instead of having them pre-buffered ahead of time.

Comment: You also don't ever seem to be painting to the frame, even though you seem to be trying. I think you need to do a lot more investigation into how painting actually works

Comment: I didn't write this code but my goal is to optimize it, so the performance issues aren't ones I created. Is there any way I can contact you for help with this? Also I'm going to look into using a jPanel